# How to check if I can connect to a server port?

Tags: command-line, connection, smtp

I have a Riseup account, but I just can't get the SMTP to work. I have tried all the tutorials, nothing. Neither Thunderbird nor Sylpheed work. Then I thought that my ISP might be blocking the ports or whatever, so I wanted to check that.

Only I don't know any (command-line) way to do it.

Something like `internety-sounding-thing mail.riseup.net:465`.

Anyone?

Comment: http://www.canyouseeme.org/ is a great tool to check if your port is open.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
 telnet <host> <port>
```

for example

```
telnet mail.riseup.net 465
```

For SSL encrypted connections (this likely is one) you can use

```
openssl s_client -connect <host>:<port>
```

for example

```
openssl s_client -connect mail.riseup.net:465
```

instead if you want to not only test if you can connect but actually talk to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I'd install the `swaks` package:

> swaks (Swiss Army Knife SMTP) is a command-line tool written in Perl
>   for  testing SMTP setups; it supports STARTTLS and SMTP AUTH (PLAIN,
>   LOGIN,  CRAM-MD5, SPA, and DIGEST-MD5). swaks allows one to stop the
>   SMTP dialog  at any stage, e.g to check RCPT TO: without actually
>   sending a mail.  .  If you are spending too much time iterating
>   "telnet foo.example 25" swaks  is for you.

Example usage:

```
swaks --to user@example.com --server test-server.example.net
```

Since it actually knows the protocol, Swaks will tell you if there's a problem other than inability to connect to the port you want so you'll get a more detailed diagnostic. Of course, you can select the protocol and the port to use independently. Check the man page which has many useful examples.